# Irrelevant Alert message before performing any image upload in django

Tags: django, django-messages

i have been working on my image upload portion of my web app and developing it using Django.My Image Upload functionality working absolutely fine.No problem with that.

But in my image upload page i am getting unnecessary alert message at a time such as "You have been singed in","You have been signed out" **after making a sign in and sign out and this alert message is appearing after entering in my image uplaod page**,which is weired!.

Yeah i have set django message tag in my Image upload template to show alert message **if user make any image upload action**.But i don't want to get any alert message such as "You have been signed in" or "You have been signed out" or something irrelevant in my image upload page after entering in my image upload page to upload an image.But unfortunately its happening and after making lot's of googling and research ,i can't figure it out.

In mention i am using django form and django message framework.

This is my view for the image upload

```
def UserImageUpload(request):   
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():         
            newdoc = Photo(photo = request.FILES['photo'],watermarked_image=request.FILES['photo'],user = request.user,name = request.POST['name'],description = request.POST['description'],keyword = request.POST['Image_Keyword'],uploaded_time=datetime.datetime.now(),Certified=request.POST['Certification'])
            newdoc.save()
            messages.success(request,'Your Image upload is waiting for Admin approval')
            form = DocumentForm         
        else:
            messages.error(request,'Please Complete All Fields or Only upload jpg file,because we are currently accepting only the jpg file!')          
    else:
        form = DocumentForm()
    uploaded_image = Photo.objects.all()    
    return render_to_response('myprofile/user_image_upload.html',{'uploaded_image':uploaded_image,'form':form},context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

and this is Image upload form template

```
{% extends 'base.html'%}

{% block title%}User Image Upload {% endblock %}

{%block content%}

<div id="messages"  style="margin-top:50px">
     {% if messages %}
      <!--<div class="row"> -->
       {% for message in messages %}
        <div class="alert alert-{{ message.tags }}">
            <!--<p{%if message.tags=="success"%} class="alert alert-success" {%endif%}>{{message}}</p> -->
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"></button>
            {{ message }}
        </div>
       {% endfor %}
      <!--</div> -->
     {% endif %}
</div>   

<div class="container" style="margin-top:5%" ng-app="ImageUpload">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4" ng-controller="ImagePreviewCtrl">
        <div class="well" ng-show="show">
  <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}            
        <p>{{ form.non_field_errors }}</p>
        <p>{{ form.photo.label_tag }} {{ form.photo.help_text }}</p>
        <ul class = 'unstyled'>             
            <li class = 'tust'>{{form.name.label}}{{ form.photo.errors }}</li>{{form.name}}<br/>
            <li class = 'tust'>{{form.description.label}}{{ form.photo.errors }}</li>{{form.description}}<br/>
            <li class = 'tust'>{{form.Image_Keyword.label}}{{ form.photo.errors }}</li>{{form.Image_Keyword}}<br/>
            <li class = 'tust'>{{form.Certification.label}}{{ form.photo.errors }}</li>{{form.Certification}}<br/>
            {{ form.photo }}                
        </ul>           
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" class="btn btn-success" />                   
     </form>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
{%endblock%}
```

**UPDATE:**

my base.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="assets/ico/favicon.png">

<title>{%block title%}Medical Art{%endblock%}</title>
<!-- TEST OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO -->

{%block css%}
<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link type = 'text/css' href="{{STATIC_URL}}photo/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Custom styles for this template -->
<!--<link type = 'text/css' href="{{STATIC_URL}}photo/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">-->

<link type = 'text/css' href="{{STATIC_URL}}photo/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link type = 'text/css' href="{{STATIC_URL}}photo/css/main-profile.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link type = 'text/css' href="{{STATIC_URL}}photo/css/car.css" rel="stylesheet">


<link  href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700,300italic,400italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link  href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
{%endblock%}



<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.3.0/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->


<script src="{{STATIC_URL}}photo/js/angular.min.js"></script>  
</head>

<body>
<div>

{%block navi%}
  <!-- Fixed navbar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default  navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
      <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'home'%}"><strong>Medical Art</strong></a>
      </div>

      <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="{% url 'showphoto'%}">Photo</a></li>
          <li><a href="{% url 'upload'%}">Upload</a></li>


        </ul>

        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3">
            <!--<form  class="navbar-form navbar-left" action='/search/search_result/' method='post' role="search">-->
            <form  class="navbar-form" action='/search/search_result/' method='post' role="search">

                <div class="input-group">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="search" id='search_item'>

                    <div class="input-group-btn">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </form>
       </div> 

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="{% url 'userena_profile_detail' user.username%}"><span style = "color:red; padding-left:5px;"> {{user.username}}!</span></a></li>
           <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Picture Management<b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li>
                <a href="{% url 'userena_profile_detail' user.username%}">Buyer</a>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="{% url 'purchased_picture' %}">&gt; My Purchased Picture</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
              </li>
              <li><a href="{% url 'userena_profile_edit' user.username%}">Contributor</a>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="{% url 'pending_images'%}">&gt; My Pending Pictures</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="{% url 'approved_images'%}">&gt; My Approved Pictures</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">&gt; My earnings</a></li>

              </li>



              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li><a href="{% url 'userena_signout'%}">Log-Out</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>

          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Account Mangement<b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="{% url 'userena_profile_detail' user.username%}">My Profile</a></li>
              <li><a href="{% url 'userena_profile_edit' user.username%}">Edit profile</a></li>
              <li><a href="{% url 'userena_password_change' user.username%}">Change password</a></li>
              <li><a href="{% url 'userena_email_change' user.username%}">Change email</a></li>


              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li><a href="{% url 'userena_signout'%}">Log-Out</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
       {%else%}
       <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">


        </ul>
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3">

        </div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="{% url 'userena_signin'%}">Sign In</a></li>
          <li><a href="{% url 'userena_signup'%}">Sign Up</span></a></li>

        </ul>
      </div>
       {% endif %}<!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </nav>


{%endblock%}

</div>
<div>{% block content%}

        <div class="endless_page_template">

          {% include 'photo/endless.html' %}

        </div>
    {% endblock%}
</div>
<br>

 {%block footer%}
 <div class="footer navbar-fixed-bottom" style="background-color:black; text-align:center">
    <h4 style = "color:#ffffff">Powered by- <a href="#">Medical Art</a> - Copyright 2014</h4>

</div>

    {%block js%}
 <script src="{{STATIC_URL}}photo/js/modernizr.custom.js"></script>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
 <script src="{{STATIC_URL}}photo/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script src="{{STATIC_URL}}photo/js/main.js"></script>
 <script src="{{STATIC_URL}}photo/js/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
 <script src="{{STATIC_URL}}photo/js/imagesloaded.js"></script>
 <script src="{{STATIC_URL}}photo/js/imageupload.js"></script>
 <script src="{{STATIC_URL}}photo/js/classie.js"></script>
 <script src="{{STATIC_URL}}photo/js/AnimOnScroll.js"></script>
 <script src="{{STATIC_URL}}photo/js/jquery.cookie.js"></script>

 <script src="{{STATIC_URL}}photo/js/endless.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"> </script> 
 <script>$.endlessPaginate({paginateOnScroll: true,paginateOnScrollMargin: 20});</script>


 <script>
    new AnimOnScroll( document.getElementById( 'grid' ), {
        minDuration : 0.4,
        maxDuration : 0.7,
        viewportFactor : 0.2
    } );
 </script>
 <script>
$(document).ready(function() {    
    //Events that reset and restart the timer animation when the slides change
    $("#transition-timer-carousel").on("slide.bs.carousel", function(event) {
        //The animate class gets removed so that it jumps straight back to 0%
        $(".transition-timer-carousel-progress-bar", this)
            .removeClass("animate").css("width", "0%");
    }).on("slid.bs.carousel", function(event) {
        //The slide transition finished, so re-add the animate class so that
        //the timer bar takes time to fill up
        $(".transition-timer-carousel-progress-bar", this)
            .addClass("animate").css("width", "100%");
    });

    //Kick off the initial slide animation when the document is ready
    $(".transition-timer-carousel-progress-bar", "#transition-timer-carousel")
        .css("width", "100%");
});
</script>

{%endblock%}


{%endblock%}

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that your messages are piling up until you enter your upload page. Then they are displayed all at once.

Moving `messages` code to your `base.html` should solve this.

**Edit**

If you will place messages just before your `content` block it will solve the issue.

```
{% if messages %}
    <div id="messages"  style="margin-top:50px">
        {% for message in messages %}
            <div class="alert alert-{{ message.tags }}">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"></button>
                {{ message }}
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>  
{% endif %}

<div id="content">
    {% block content%}
        <div class="endless_page_template">
            {% include 'photo/endless.html' %}
        </div>
    {% endblock%}
</div>
```

Comment: There is  no code for messages in my base.html @Yossi

Comment: I know. You should move it over from upload template to `base.html`

Comment: i have added messages code from my uploaded template to base.html and added it in the content portion of the base.html,but now no message is showing even thoung i make an image upload action.

Comment: Hard to tell without access to your code. I believe that you override the messages portion of `base.html` in you upload template. therefore no messages are displayed.

Comment: Though there is no message in the upload page after the addition of  the messages code into the base.html's content portion,now alert messages for each action of image upload is showing in my homepage.I suspect,this is happening because i have added the messages code in the base.html which in fact extended in every page including the home page. @Yossi

Comment: Please read my comment above. Messages code must be defined in base.html. Messages code should not be overrided by inheriting blocks. Follow these rules, and everything will work as expected.

Comment: can you please give me an example how to define messages code into base.html,i have added my base.html file in my post. @Yossi